# Wyse Z Class Thin Client (WES7) Image Deployment

Tags: imaging, thin-client, windows-embedded

We are currently working on deploying a few Wyse WES7 thin clients (Z Class, exact model escapes me at the moment).

We have WDM setup, and are able to see new clients show up, interact with them, pull/push images. Our current workflow is something like this:

1. Unpack & boot up the device
2. Disable Windows Firewall, reboot
3. Device shows up in WDM
4. Publish our custom image to the new device.

My question is whether or not there is a way I can bypass step 2, and put my image on the client right out of the box. Either using PXE or USB boot disk, such that I can boot into some sort of menu and tell the client to pull a particular image from the WDM server.

With HP thin clients, we have a rule setup which detects new clients on the network and pushes our custom image to them first time they show up. I haven't been able to figure it out with Wyse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after digging around, I found out about DDC, Default Device Configuration.

[Documentatoin on Wyse KB](https://support.wyse.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=20485&nUsePub=NO&jttst0=6_23871,23871,-1,0,&jtfm0=&etfm1=&jfn=ZG36201BF6444554E285BA2D171A55A3613B5F10DB0D71F21335E6D1F81CD36D5F8C59C7689A706109EE1815C89819A4EC1B&oas=YCFQDllCOY1vqg6kTdCNkQ)

Furthermore, you may also need to follow this if you want to push a custom image through DDC:

[Non-PXE imaging for XPe/WES 2009/WES 7 in WDM with Default Device Configuration (DDC)](http://midwestwyseguy.com/2011/03/how-to-non-pxe-imaging-for-xpewes-2009wes-7-in-wdm-with-default-device-configuration-ddc/)